# LSOpenCFURLRef won't open file with ;

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

i have a problem with this code:

```
    CFStringRef URL =  CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, url.ToString().c_str(), kCFStringEncodingASCII);
    CFURLRef pathRef = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, URL, NULL);
    if (pathRef) {
        OSStatus status = LSOpenCFURLRef(pathRef, NULL);
```

i'm receiving paths in the form

```
   "file:///Users/x/Documents/5%20Sample%20of%20Small%20Construction%20Plan%20(A0+).htg"
```

LSOpenCFURLRef manages to open the file with the above path, but if the path includes semicolons LSOpenCFURLRef fails with -43 (not found)

if i replace ; with %3B it works, but this seems like a patch, not a solution.

if the incoming path is fully url encoded then CFURLCreateWithString fails and returns NULL so I cannot call LSOpenCFURLRef

Answer (score 0):

to make it work i had to unescape the text and then escape it again by explicitly specifying in CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes which characters to escape (adding ; to the list)